# How to solve this non linear equation?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, nonlinear

The non linear equation is in the form of $k\sin(wt)=w'$. Please send help. Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to use Dsolve but it didnt work after I tried for 1 hour so I gave up.

Comment: Why didn't you show your code ? Try  `DSolve[k Sin[w[t]] == w'[t], w, t]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  It is a nonlinear equation, `k*Sin[w[t]*t]==w'[t]`

Comment: As suggested by @UlrichNeumann, `DSolveValue[k Sin[w[t]] == w'[t], w[t], t]` yields `2 ArcCot[E^(-k t - C[1])]`.  Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

tmax = 5;

w0 = 1;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[
  {k Sin[w[t]] == w'[t], w[0] == w0}, w, {t, 0, tmax}, {k}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[w[k][t] /. sol, {k, 1, 3}],
 {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[
  {k Sin[w[t]*t] == w'[t], w[0] == w0}, w, {t, 0, tmax}, {k}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[w[k][t] /. sol2, {k, 1, 3}],
 {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]